# using parameters in vba class

Tags: excel, parameters, vba

Presently i have a vba which i am using as an add-in in excel to call some UDF.  the functions take in parameters such as a range of numbers, and some attributes about these numbers and constants.

e.g. ROR(some_range_of_numbers,weekly)

the second parameter has the following options. it could be either Daily or weekly or monthly or quarterly or annual.  if its daily i use 365, if its weekly i use 52, if its monthly i use 12 if its Qtrly then i use 4 and Annual i use 1 as one of the components of the formula in the UDF.

now, my question is when the user wants to use the function, i want to force the user to input daily or weekly etc.  i remember something about using types or parameters in VB.  But am lost here.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below function:

```
Function ROR(rng As Range, interval As String) 


    Dim intervalNum As Integer
    select Case LCase(interval)

    Case "daily":
        intervalNum = 365
    Case "weekly":
        intervalNum = 52
    Case "monthly":
        intervalNum = 12
    Case "quarterly":
        intervalNum = 4
    Case "annual":
        intervalNum = 1
    End Select

Debug.Print intervalNum

End Function
```

Updated code after comments :

```
Enum interval
    daily = 365
    weekly = 52
    monthly = 12
    quarterly = 4
    annual = 1
End Enum

Function ROR(rng As Integer, val As interval)


End Function
```

Also you can use type wherein you will get it as dropdownlist.

```
Type interval
    daily As Integer
    weekly As Integer
    monthly As Integer
    quarterly As Integer
    annual As Integer
End Type
```

[image]

Comment: i already have this.  i was looking for drop down kind of list of parameters.

Comment: ok am checking it ... on the vba ... ENUM that is what i am looking for ... i think ... checking ....  now

Comment: ok enum works fine within the module and the class.  but not outside.  atleast partial achieve.  besides the url provided by @mehow should help reach somewhere.  Thanks